# no intellisense for code inside handlers (ashx files)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ashx

I have a Web Site project. When opened with Visual Studio 2013 the intellisense is working fine, but when opened with Visual Studio Professional 2015 the intellisense is fail in ashx files. For example: Goto definition or Find all references for functions are not works. There is also no color change for class names.

I was try to compare Text Editor settings and do Reset all settings, but hopeless. It seems like intellisense is refuse to work inside ashx files.
How can I fix it?

PS. I have read the post about dividing ashx to 2 files, when all c# code will be inside cs file. This may work, but I have a lot of ashx files and don't want to double this amount, also this project intellisense is working in VS2013, so there should be a workaround for VS2015